# How to calculate 'start' & 'end' angle of an Arc by given 2 points?

Tags: javascript, math, processing, trigonometry, p5.js

I've been trying to draw an `arc` on the canvas, using p5.js. I got start & end points, the chord length i calculate using `pythagoras` using the two points, the height & width values are also given.

In order to draw an arc, i need to use the following function;
`arc(x, y, w, h, start, stop, [mode], [detail])` for docs refer to [here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/arc)

The `start` & `stop` parameters refer to the start&stop angles specified in radians. I can't draw the arc without those angles and i'm unable to calculate them using what i got.

I searched for lots of examples similar to my question, but it is suggested to calculate the center angle, which i'm also unable to do so. Even though i was able to calculate the center angle, how i'm supposed to get the start&stop angles afterwards?

I have drawn some example illustrations on GeoGebra;
[image: Initial Given Stuff]

[image: Final Arc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle of a vector can be calculated by [`atan2()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/atan2).

Note, that:

```js
tan(alpha) = sin(alpha) / cos(alpha)
```

If you've a vector (`x`, `y`), then than angle (`alpha`) of the vector relative to the x-axis is:

```js
alpha = atan2(y, x);
```

The `start_angle` and `stop_angle` of an arc, where the center of the arc is (`cpt_x`, `cpt_y`), the start point is (`spt_x`, `spt_y`) and the end point is (`ept_x`, `ept_y`), can be calculated by:

```js
start_angle = atan2(spt_y-cpt_y, spt_x-cpt_x);
stop_angle  = atan2(ept_y-cpt_y, ept_x-cpt_x);
```

See the example, where the stop angle depends on the mouse position:

```js
var sketch = function( p ) {

p.setup = function() {
    let sketchCanvas = p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
    sketchCanvas.parent('p5js_canvas')
}

p.windowResized = function() {
    p.resizeCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
}

p.draw = function() {

    let cpt        = new p5.Vector(p.width/2, p.height/2);
    let rad        = p.min(p.width/2, p.height/2) * 0.9;
    let stop_angle = p.atan2(p.mouseY-cpt.y, p.mouseX-cpt.x);

    p.background(192);
    p.stroke(255, 64, 64);
    p.strokeWeight(3);
    p.noFill();
    p.arc(cpt.x, cpt.y, rad*2, rad*2, 0, stop_angle);
}

};

var circle = new p5(sketch);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
<div id="p5js_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Well, i'm impressed about the detailed explanation! Works like a charm. I guess i need to learn some geometry for cs graphics, any advice for a book or a tutorial collection?

Comment: @AhmetGokdayi Thank you. You're welcome. Sorry but I don't know a good tutorial. Google found [THIS](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html) and [THIS](http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys311.old/lectures/vector/vector.html), which looks promising. [`p5.Vector`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) implements the vector arithmetic in p5.js.